# socket undefined in callback for connect

Tags: socket.io

Why is the socket in the callback undefined?

```
main.js:26078 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
```

The console log is a Socket object.

```
var jwt = sessionStorage.token;
console.log(socket);
socket.on('connect', function (socket) {  // undefined socket
  socket.on('authenticated', function () {
    //do other things
  })
  .emit('authenticate', {token: jwt}); //send the jwt
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this is client code, there is no `socket` argument passed to the `connect` event, so remove that from your code.  By naming that argument `socket`, you were overriding the higher scoped `socket` variable and since nothing is passed to that event, this overridden `socket` variable will then be `undefined`.  Change to this:

```
var jwt = sessionStorage.token;
console.log(socket);
// remove socket argument from this next callback
socket.on('connect', function () {
  socket.on('authenticated', function () { // undefined socket
    //do other things
  })
  .emit('authenticate', {token: jwt}); //send the jwt
});
```

Comment: Why did the example here have a socket in the callback? https://github.com/auth0/socketio-jwt#example-usage

Comment: @amiawizard - That client example looks wrong.  The socket.io client doc does not show any argument to the callback for the `connect` event.

Comment: @amiawizard - Did this answer your original question?

Comment: Yes it answers the question